# my python package can be installed on my local conda env but can not be installed on other envs or systems

Tags: python, package, dependencies, pypi, python-packaging

I have created my own python package and uploaded it in https://test.pypi.org/ which installed and worked fine in my conda virtual environment but when I want to install it on other systems or environments, it seems that it cant install the dependencies.
i get this error:

```
ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
```

my setup.py file is:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setup(
    name = "mypackage",
    version = "0.0.31",
    author = "my name",
    author_email= "email@gmail.com",
    description = "a description",
    long_description = long_description,
    long_description_content_type = "text/markdown",
    packages = ["mypackage"],
    python_requires = ">=3.9",
    install_requires = [
        "pandas>=1.4.2",
        "pyro-api>=0.1.2",
        "pyro-ppl>=1.8.0",
        "numpy>=1.21.5",
        ],
)
```

I'm on **Ubuntu 22.04** and using following commands to install the package:

- python setup.py sdist
- twine upload --repository testpypi dist/mypackage-0.0.31.tar.gz
- pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/mypackage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the command

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/mypackage
```

you provide only the index but not the requirement(s). The correct syntax is

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ mypackage
```

Also with

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ mypackage
```

you allowed pip to install only from test.pypi.org and there is no `pandas>=1.3.3` at https://test.pypi.org/project/pandas. You need to allow pip to use pypi.org. This way:

```
pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple mypackage
```

Comment: I tried it but got this message: Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: mypackage in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.0.15)

Comment: @Azad So you have the package already installed.

Comment: But none of the dependencies has been installed, can't import the package and any of the dependencies

Comment: Uninstall, reinstall and show if there're any errors. Or just force-reinstall.

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas>=1.3.3 (from mypackage) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas>=1.3.3

Comment: i got above errors, but in my conda env i used "conda search pandas" command and it has all the versions of pandas.

Comment: With `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/` you allowed `pip` to install only from `test.pypi.org` and there is no `pandas>=1.3.3` at https://test.pypi.org/project/pandas/ . You need to allow `pip` to use `pypi.org`. This way: `pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple mypackage`

Comment: great, problem solved, as you said it was matter of "test.pypi.org" which pandas and I guess other packages are not included there. thanks